# Wait for parent window to reload and then close popup

Tags: progress-bar

I am showing "Please wait" message in a popup window.
It should wait until parent page get refresh.
Calling function like this closes the popup immediately and then refresh the parent window.
Ideally it should wait until parent get refreshed and then it should be closed.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
var myWindow;
function submitForm() {
myWindow = window.open("",""); // works fine
window.parent.location.reload(true);
}
closeWindow(){
    myWindow.close();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    submitForm();
    closeWindow();
});
</script>
```

Comment: On Refresh the parent would lose reference to the popup window so wouldn't be able to close it.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments the refresh of the parent would lose the reference to the popup window.

One solution for this is to use a css modal instead. such that on click of your button you submit form but you also show a modal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#openModal').hide();

    $('#button').click(function(e) {
        $('#openModal').fadeIn('slow');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When the page is refreshed the dialog will be hidden.

*Note: If your `submitForm` method is being called from the submit button of your form reload would happen before the submit effectively losing the data take a look at posting your data via AJAX which would avoid a refresh of the page in total (you would have to hide the modal too with `$('#openModal').hide();`)*

full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xH6Hj/2/)